# How to read x,y pairs into numpy to plot when some of the data is text = N/A

Tags: python, numpy

I am trying to plot data x,y pairs. The data is read in using the statement

```
x, y = np.loadtxt(item + '_' + 'Test.csv', skiprows=1, usecols=[4, 5], unpack=True, delimiter=',')
```

but I know some of the x or y data will contain the string `N/A` and so I will need to skip these pairs. Is there a function in NumPy that might help me with this( something similar in VBA uses ISNUMBER) - could anyone give me some advice, please? Thanks

Comment: Can you please add a sample of data that you would be reading?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `numpy.genfromtxt` with an appropriate setting for the `missing_values` option.

```py
x, y = np.genfromtxt(
    item + '_' + 'Test.csv',
    skiprows=1,
    usecols=[4, 5],
    unpack=True,
    delimiter=',',
    missing_values={'N/A'},
)
```

Then, to get rid of the rows with missing data, you can use:

```py
valid = np.isfinite(x) & np.isfinite(y)
x, y = x[valid], y[valid]
```